# Ошибка: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, lxml

В чем ошибка?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

FILE="games.csv"

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text



def get_link(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
    video = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "highlight_player_item", "data-mp4-hd-source": True})

    for item in video:
        games.append({'video':item["data-mp4-hd-source"]})


def save_file(items, path):
    with open(path, 'w', newline='', encoding='cp1251') as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=';')
        writer.writerow(['VIDEOS'])
        for item in items:
            writer.writerow([item['video']])
games=[]
with open("racesru.csv", newline='', encoding='cp1251') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        link = row[4]
        if (link != '0' and link != 'LINK'):
            url = link
            print(url)
            print(games)
            save_file(games, FILE)
            get_link(get_html(str(url)))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В самой ошибке вроде написано в чем она, не?

Comment: @Эникейщик это то я понял, просто не знаю как ее исправить

Comment: Вы получаете строковый индекс у строки, чтобы исправить - не делайте так.

Comment: Разобраться с тем, что вы хотите сделать, с тем, что происходит в каждой функции, и соответствующим образом исправить код, принимая во внимание причину ошибки.

Comment: @vp_arth  просто если вместо soup.find написать soup.find_all, то все работает, но он парсит несколько элементов с таким классом с этой страницы, а мне надо только первый

Comment: Если вам нужно только первый, то может вам не нужен цикл? `{'video': video['data-mp4-hd-source']}`

Comment: @vp_arth да, теперь все работает

Answer (score 0):

Переменная `item` в вашем коде содержит строку. У строки нет символа с номером `data-mp4-hd-source`.

Сложно понять, что вы хотели выразить этим кодом, но предположу, что достаточно будет добавлять сами итемы:

```
games.append({'video': item})
```

Comment: к сожалению, не помогло